# Software to perform static analysis on PHP 5.3 code and help migrate to PHP 5.6/PHP 7

Tags: php, static-analysis

I've a old codebase written in PHP 5.3, which I'm planning to migrate to PHP 5.6 (at least) or if possible, PHP 7.

Are there tools that can do static analysis of the code and give me a list of things to change, for migration? I can't do this manually as the code base has tens of thousands of files. I'd need to automate at least part of the process.

Comment: One tip for you - __before__ you start write __lots__ and lots of tests - that way you can make ___sure___ that the new code still runs at least as well as the old.

Comment: AFAIK, PHP 5.6 is backwards compatible with 5.3.  Do you have counterexamples?

Comment: @IraBaxter magic quotes, for example. It has been removed from 5.4 onwards, right? There are thousands of queries that I need to fix

Comment: If you really plan on updating tens of thousands of files, wouldn't you want a tool that could actually make the changes? (At one minute each if you were lucky enough to be that fast it would take you a solid month, and it likely takes longer to checkout/edit/test/checkin)  [Check my bio]

Comment: Do you a have reference to all the backwards compatibility breaking changes?  The change log http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php suggests several things that are deprecated, but it mostly doesn't say they are removed, and it doesn't mention magic quotes at all.

Comment: Found a list of changes between versions: http://php.net/manual/en/migration5.php

Comment: @IraBaxter Yes, absolutely. If there is a tool that can safely make the changes, then sure. But that is the second step. I need to first make a full impact analysis to convince my bosses that it is worth doing it and tell them the risks and effort

Comment: @user1336: I'd like to have a direct conversation with you, if you don't mind. You can find an email contact for me at my bio to initiate that discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Two that come to mind are [PHP Depend](https://pdepend.org/documentation/what-is-php-depend.html) and [PHP Mess Detector](https://phpmd.org/).

PHP Depend uses several [software metrics](https://pdepend.org/documentation/software-metrics/index.html) to evaluate the code.  PHP Mess Detector is a relatively new tool that takes a different approach by using a limited [rule set](https://phpmd.org/rules/index.html) to evaluate the code.  PHP Depend requires PHP 5.2.3 while PHP Mess Detector requires 5.3.0.

Lastly, you may consider using the PHP “-l” command line option (syntax check) in an automated process.

Comment: While these may be useful tools for assessing code quality, they are not specifically useful with respect to OP's request.